# blat command to mail the report to the given mail ID

Tags: command, blat

One of our report is using blat command to mail the report to the given mail ID.

The ***first step*** produces the PDF file and saves it in the server (this step is working fine).

The ***second step*** uses the blat services to send the PDF to given mail ID.But, this step is not working correctly. Some other reports which uses the blat services on the same server are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the command line you're using?  It may be that you have 'spaces' in your file name and don't have it properly quoted.